# How can i get the number and their unit?

Tags: javascript, regex

i want to create a regex to "- any number + unit" in a string

for example i have this string:

```
hello- world- 86 lo.  => 86 lo


in the -world- 6 lb   => 6 lb



and- the- dog -8kl     => 8kl
```

```js
let data='in the world- 6 lo'

let  reg =  /-[0-9][a-z]/gi;
let matches = data.match(reg);
console.log(matches)
```

with his answer:

```js
let data='in the world- 6 lo'

    let  reg =  /-\s*([0-9]+\s*[a-z]+)/;
    let matches = data.match(reg);
    console.log(matches)
```

i get two answer
[
"- 6 lo",
"6 lo"
]

i want to get only the second => "6 lo"

Comment: @Thefourthbird but there are many '-' in my strings

Comment: All of your examples show the number & unit at the _end_ of the string. Will these _always_ be at the end?

Comment: Is this fine ? ` -(\s?\d+\s?\w\w)` - https://regex101.com/r/mD9JeR/9

Comment: Ah you updated the question, try `-\s*([0-9]+\s*[a-z]+)` https://regex101.com/r/EP89vc/1 and take the group 1 value.

Comment: `-\s*(\d+\s*[a-z]+)`  https://regex101.com/r/hzqrsF/1

Comment: I got this `-[ ]?\d+\w*([ ]\w+)?``

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Match the hyphen and 0+ whitespace chars. The capture in **group 1** matching 1+ digits, optional whitespace chars and 1 or more chars a-z.

A specific match with an optional decimal part, adding the units:

```
-\s*([0-9]+(?:\.\d+)?(?:\s*(?:l[ob]|kl))?)\b
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fslAXw/1)

```js
const regex = /-\s*([0-9]+(?:\.\d+)?(?:\s*(?:l[ob]|kl))?)\b/g;
const str = `hello- world- 86 lo
in the -world- 6 lb
and- the- dog -8kl
hello- world- 86.6 lo
hello- world- 86`;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
  console.log(m[1]);
}
```

Or a more broad match:

```
-\s*([0-9]+(?:\.\d+)?(?:\s*[a-z]+)?)\b
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/1O1ctU/1)

```js
const regex = /-\s*([0-9]+(?:\.\d+)?(?:\s*[a-z]+)?)\b/g;
const str = `hello- world- 86 lo
in the -world- 6 lb
and- the- dog -8kl
hello- world- 86.6 lo
hello- world- 86`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
  console.log(m[1]);
}
```

Comment: i get null  const regex = /-\s*([0-9]+\s*[a-z]+)/g;
    const str = `hello- world- 86`;
    let m;

    m = regex.exec(str)
    console.log(m);

Comment: @jdode That is because there is not unit after `hello- world- 86` If `86` should be a match, you can make the last part optional `-\s*([0-9]+\s*(?:l[ob]|kl)?)\b` https://regex101.com/r/C2xNdq/1

Comment: @jdode See the previous comment. This will get a single value `const regex = /-\s*([0-9]+\s*(?:l[ob]|kl)?)\b/g; 
    const str = `hello- world- 86`; 
    let m; 
    m = regex.exec(str) ;
    console.log(m[1]);` Use the while loop if you want all the values.

Comment: @jdode Yes to get a single value you could use `m[1]` I have added an update to the answer.

Comment: if dont exist the unit i want to get the number, in other case i want to get the number + unit, with this /-\s*([0-9]+\s*(?:l[ob]|kl)?)\b/g      i only get the number

Comment: @jdode You can see the code snippets that using this pattern you will get the number if there is no unit, or the number and the unit if it is present. Also see https://regex101.com/r/AEtDFh/1

Comment: to 'hello- world- 86.6 lo' dont worked, fraction numbers

Comment: @jdode Then you could use an optional decimal part `-\s*([0-9]+(?:\.\d+)?(?:\s*(?:l[ob]|kl))?)\b` See  https://regex101.com/r/fslAXw/1

Answer (score 0):

```js
let data='in the world- 6 lo'

let  reg =  /\d+\s?[A-Za-z]{2}/gi;
let matches = data.match(reg);
console.log(matches)
```

try this, you can replace `[A-Za-z]` with the only units you need.

Answer (score 0):

Well your data is a little odd, especially in the last case where it seems like the value might be negative. However, this regex should work for the cases you describe, and you can recombine the parts (sign, value, and unit) in whatever way you want afterward.

```js
let data1 = 'in the world- 6 lo'
let data2 = 'in the -world- 6 lb'
let data3 = 'and- the- dog -8kl'

let  reg = /- ?(-|\+)?(\d+\.?\d*) ?(\w+)/;

[data1, data2, data3].forEach(s => {
  console.log("Checking string:", s);
  const matches = s.match(reg);
  console.log("Sign:", matches[1] ?? "+");
  console.log("Value:", matches[2]);
  console.log("Unit:", matches[3]);
});
```

Note that I'd avoid using the global flag `g` since it prevents the `.match` method from returning the contents of each capture group.

Answer (score 0):

Make a match against the regexp and then map the result-array of this to get rid of the "- " at the beginning and return it.
In the regexp the minus had to be masked with , the spaces are optional, the unit accept all letters. If there are e.g. only max 2 letters wished than add {1,2}.
Because you wanted all results in the string (the g-parameter) I can't use the brackets in the regexp. So I had to map over the results and use here another regexp to get the desired part of the results.

```js
function test(str) {
  let reg =  /\- ?[0-9]+ ?[a-z]+/gi;
  let result = str.match(reg);
  return result.map(res => {
    return res.match(/\- ?(.*)/)[1];
  });
}

console.log(test('hello- world- 86 lo, test-912 kg.'));
console.log(test('in the -world- 6 lb '));
console.log(test('and- the- dog -8kl'));
```